# Error while Running SAP for Java

Tags: java

I have installed SAP 7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and it was working fine. but from last few days its not working. Only Splash Screen shows and its goes.

I have tried to start with terminal then it shows errors.

Please Help

```
#/opt/SAPClients/SAPGUI7.30rev1/bin$ ./guilogon 
############################# ERROR #############################
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR: Exception occured: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.platin.r3.trace.NativeTraceHook
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.platin.r3.trace.NativeTraceHook
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.createClass(Dynamic.java:100)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.createObject(Dynamic.java:73)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.createObject(Dynamic.java:57)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.application.GuiApplication.<init>(GuiApplication.java:176)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.automation.GuiClassDescriptor.newInstance(GuiClassDescriptor.java:124)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.automation.GuiAutomationDispatcher.createObject(GuiAutomationDispatcher.java:127)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.automation.GuiAutomationDispatcher.createApplication(GuiAutomationDispatcher.java:96)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.application.GuiApplication.currentApplication(GuiApplication.java:246)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl.evalCommandLine(GuiImpl.java:534)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl.<init>(GuiImpl.java:143)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl.main(GuiImpl.java:793)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Microkernel.startApplication(Microkernel.java:334)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Microkernel.startApplication(Microkernel.java:173)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.callMethod(Dynamic.java:127)
25.06. 11:42:22.304 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.Gui.main(Gui.java:74)
############################# ERROR #############################
############################# ERROR #############################
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR: Exception occured: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.platin.r3.util.GuiIconList
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.platin.r3.util.GuiIconList
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.createClass(Dynamic.java:100)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.createClass(Dynamic.java:82)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiBitmapMgr.<clinit>(GuiBitmapMgr.java:41)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.basic.BasicSAPConfigurator.setDefaultIconsImpl(BasicSAPConfigurator.java:60)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.basic.BasicSAPConfigurator.initDefaults(BasicSAPConfigurator.java:54)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.plaf.DesignLookAndFeel.getDefaults(DesignLookAndFeel.java:309)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:536)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl$1.run(GuiImpl.java:104)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.event.GuiEventQueue.dispatchEvent(GuiEventQueue.java:79)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
25.06. 11:42:22.473 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
############################# ERROR #############################
############################# ERROR #############################
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR: Exception occured: java.lang.NullPointerException
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.getProperty(Dynamic.java:247)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.Dynamic.getProperty(Dynamic.java:234)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiBitmapMgr.<clinit>(GuiBitmapMgr.java:41)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.basic.BasicSAPConfigurator.setDefaultIconsImpl(BasicSAPConfigurator.java:60)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.basic.BasicSAPConfigurator.initDefaults(BasicSAPConfigurator.java:54)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.plaf.DesignLookAndFeel.getDefaults(DesignLookAndFeel.java:309)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:536)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl$1.run(GuiImpl.java:104)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at com.sap.platin.micro.event.GuiEventQueue.dispatchEvent(GuiEventQueue.java:79)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
25.06. 11:42:22.474 ERROR:  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
############################# ERROR #############################
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.basic.BasicSAPConfigurator.setDefaultIconsImpl(BasicSAPConfigurator.java:60)
    at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.basic.BasicSAPConfigurator.initDefaults(BasicSAPConfigurator.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sap.platin.base.plaf.DesignLookAndFeel.getDefaults(DesignLookAndFeel.java:309)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:536)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl$1.run(GuiImpl.java:104)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.sap.platin.micro.event.GuiEventQueue.dispatchEvent(GuiEventQueue.java:79)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiBitmapMgr.<clinit>(GuiBitmapMgr.java:42)
    ... 24 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiBitmapMgr
    at com.sap.platin.base.plaf.frog.hueshift.PlatinSystemHueShift.initThemeSpecificDef(PlatinSystemHueShift.java:81)
    at com.sap.platin.r3.plaf.frog.FrogSAPConfigurator.initDefaults(FrogSAPConfigurator.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sap.platin.base.plaf.DesignLookAndFeel.getDefaults(DesignLookAndFeel.java:350)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:536)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl$1.run(GuiImpl.java:104)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.sap.platin.micro.event.GuiEventQueue.dispatchEvent(GuiEventQueue.java:79)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiBitmapMgr
    at com.sap.platin.wdp.plaf.ur.WdpUrConfigurator.initUrComponentDefaults(WdpUrConfigurator.java:61)
    at com.sap.plaf.ur.UrConfigurator.initDefaults(UrConfigurator.java:241)
    at com.sap.platin.wdp.plaf.ur.WdpUrConfigurator.initDefaults(WdpUrConfigurator.java:47)
    at com.sap.platin.wdp.plaf.ur.WdpUrConfigurator.getDefaults(WdpUrConfigurator.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sap.platin.base.plaf.DesignLookAndFeel.getDefaults(DesignLookAndFeel.java:400)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:536)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl$1.run(GuiImpl.java:104)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.sap.platin.micro.event.GuiEventQueue.dispatchEvent(GuiEventQueue.java:79)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.platin.base.util.GuiBitmapMgr
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiLogon.initComponents(GuiLogon.java:1369)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiLogon.<init>(GuiLogon.java:291)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiLogon.getLogonFrame(GuiLogon.java:1344)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiLogonManager.getLogonFrame(GuiLogonManager.java:60)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiLogonManager.setVisibleLogonFrame(GuiLogonManager.java:78)
    at com.sap.platin.base.logon.GuiImpl$2.run(GuiImpl.java:164)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.sap.platin.micro.event.GuiEventQueue.dispatchEvent(GuiEventQueue.java:79)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Which java version (oracle or openJDK) do you use?

Comment: #java -version 
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

So [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-34551#section24) is the final solution: use SAPGUI java 730 rev 3 that was just released...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Debian Jessie/sid, and the latest java SE 1.7.0_25 from Oracle.
Reverting the java to 1.7.0_21 makes saplogon work again !

Comment: where to find 1.7.0_21 ???

Comment: Only revert to an old Java version as a last resort. A lot of security patches take place - always be sure to run the latest version. If that does not work for the application you're trying to run, report this to your software vendor.

Comment: I agree, thats not a real solution, only an ugly workaround. Hopefully there will be a java SE 1.7.0_26 soon that fixes that.

Comment: I have revert java to 1.6.0_45 and now its working. Thank you all...

Comment: Aren't there security issues with older java versions?